# How to Copy Artifacts from other Jenkins Job from a Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to copy a build artifact from another Jenkins Job using the CopyArtifact plugin.

The artifact is created using the following command:

```
archiveArtifacts artifacts: '_Builds/BuildRelease/**', fingerprint: true
build 'Release Installer'
```

Within the 'Release Installer'  job, I try the obtain the archived artifacts
using the following command within the Pipeline:

```
  stages {
    stage('Get Artifacts') {
        steps {
            step([  $class: 'CopyArtifact',
                    projectName: "MyBuildJob",
                    filter: "_Builds/BuildRelease/archive.zip"
            ])
        }
    }
```

When the "Release Installer" Job is executed, the artifact is not found.
Both jobs are executed on the same Build node.

I think my filter rule is missing something. Unfortunately the available Jenkins documentation is a little thin on details and examples.

Comment: "the available Jenkins documentation is a little thin on details" you must be a really nice person who made an effort to see the positive side, I'd say Jenkins documentation sucks!

Comment: By the way, I think you need `stash`/`unstash` commands for doing that: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the default is to copy from the last successful job.  However, it looks like you currently want the upstream job.  Here is a snippet:

```
copyArtifacts fingerprintArtifacts: true, projectName: 'MyBuildJob', selector: upstream()
```

I generated this code using the snippet generator.  It should exist on the left panel of the classic view of a job.  The button text reads "Pipeline Syntax" and the url is "my.jenkins.instance.com/pipeline-syntax/"

Specifying an artifact filter is not required, it will copy all of them.  However if you want to keep the filter:

```
copyArtifacts filter: '_Builds/BuildRelease/archive.zip', fingerprintArtifacts: true, projectName: 'MyBuildJob', selector: upstream()
```